# e.touches[0].pageY returns undefined

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

I am trying to handle a touch down event on mobile for a draggable element. I have an event listener that can tell if the user is on mobile or a desktop. If the user is on mobile then the variable `isTouched` = True otherwise it is False. If true the else block with `e.target.style.top = (e.touches[0].pageY - (e.target.offsetHeight /2 )) + 'px';` runs and this is where the problem lies. `(e.touches[0].pageY` or `(e.touches[0].pageX` both return undefined. The exact error code that I get is this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.handleMouseDown
```

Here is the code for my project.

```
function handleMouseDown(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("draggable")){
        document.getElementById("wrapper").append(draggedWord);
        e.target.style.position = "absolute";

        if (isTouched == false) {
            e.target.style.top = (e.pageY - (e.target.offsetHeight /2 )) + 'px';
            e.target.style.left = (e.pageX - (e.target.offsetWidth / 2)) + 'px';

        } else {
              e.target.style.top = (e.touches[0].pageY - (e.target.offsetHeight /2 )) + 'px';
              e.target.style.left = (e.touches[0].pageX - (e.target.offsetWidth / 2)) + 'px';


                }
                                
            }
        }
```

And the EventListener that sets the isTouched variable is here.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
        isTouched = true;
     });

     window.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
         isTouched = false;
     });
```

I call the function above with these eventListeners

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("mousedown",handleMouseDown);
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("touchstart",handleMouseDown);
```

Comment: It is important to see where 'e' is coming from and in which context you call the if block...

Comment: i just updated my code. thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: e.touches[0].pageY and e.touches[0].pageX are both correct and the handler gets the event 'e' --- sorry, i dont know where is the error - maybe you could console.log(e) to find something useful...

Comment: Console log e. I will give it a whirl. I'm actually new to javascript so this is all incredibly complicated for me. But it is so wierd. I have no idea of why it doesnt work either

Comment: Do you think that this maybe doesnt work on chrome?

Comment: No, i tested both succesful in chrome and firefox. Did you watch in your browser console - and if yes, what did your script spit out?

Comment: My console just sent me the error that I posted in the question and I know that its thr parts in question that cause the error because when I comment them out of the code I do not get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem! I simply needed to add a `preventDefault()` to the else branch

```
else {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.style.top = (e.touches[0].pageY - (e.target.offsetHeight /2 )) + 'px';
      e.target.style.left = (e.touches[0].pageX - (e.target.offsetWidth / 2)) + 'px';
```